# My component in my modal is rerendering twice

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have one parent component that open a modal based in a variable value:

```
const [openFullScreenModal, setOpenFullScreenModal] = useState(false)
```

I have one button that set this variable to `true`:

```
setOpenFullScreenModal(true)
```

In my template i have the modal that opens when `openFullScreenModal` is `true`:

```
{ openFullScreenModal === true ? 
    <ModalFullScreen
        FormComponent={UsersFormPermissionsGroupPermissions}
        title="Permissões do grupo"
        onCloseModal={setOpenFullScreenModal}
        open={openFullScreenModal}
    />
    :
    <> </>
}
```

This is my **ModalFullScreen** component:

```
const ModalFullScreen = (props) => {

    const { title, FormComponent, open, onCloseModal } = props
    const classes = modalFullScreenStyles()

    const handleClose = () => {
        onCloseModal(false)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Dialog fullScreen open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
                <AppBar className={classes.appBar}>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
                            {title}
                        </Typography>
                        <IconButton edge="start" color="inherit" onClick={handleClose} aria-label="fechar">
                            <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
                                Cancelar
                            </Typography>
                        </IconButton>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>

                <FormComponent></FormComponent>

            </Dialog>
        </div>
    )
```

In my **UsersFormPermissionsGroupPermissions** i use an `useEffect()` to get data from an api:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('mounted again')
    dispatch(groupPermissionsActions.getPermissionsGroupById(idGroupCompany))
})
```

I noticed that my api is being called twice, so i put this `console.log()` and confirmed that when i click in the button in my parent component, my modal open and the component that i'm passing to my modal is re-render twice.

Why this is happening? How i can fix this?

Comment: Please create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) example. It will be much easier to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UseEffect()`, if not specified, will be called for every prop/state update. You should specify in the `useEffect` when the call should be made using an additional parameter

```
useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch(yourAction());
},[shouldUpdateVar]);
```

If you write it like this, your effect will be only called when the `shouldUpdateVar` variable is changing.

If you want the update to be only run once, you can use an empty array `useEffect(callback,[])`

You can see it in the docs [useEffect conditional](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect)

Comment: Thanks, i forget to put the [] in my use effect, now, my component is rendering only one time:     useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(groupPermissionsActions.getPermissionsGroupById(idGroupCompany))
    }, [])

Comment: Indeed, you can also use the empty array if you want it only run once, I'll update my answer, glad I helped !